# Show uitextview with keypad and toolbar when editing textfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextview, inputaccessoryview, inputview

[image]

What is the right approach to achieve what you see in the gif? It's a tableview with textfields. When you tap a textfield, a textview shows up with it's keypad. I have a tableview with a custom tableviewcell with a textfield(valueTextField). And in cellforrow i set the inputview of the textfield to a UITextView. When i press the textfield, the textview is supposed to show the toolbar on top (with a "Done" button) but no toolbar shows. When i tap the textview, still no toolbar.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! EditProfileTableViewCell
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.valueTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.valueTextField.delegate = self
    toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(editorDone))
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

    editorTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.bounds.width, height:view.bounds.height))
    cell.valueTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        cell.valueTextField.inputView = editorTextView

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you show is simply using a `UINavigationController` to navigate to a separate `UIViewController` when the cell is tapped. In this view controller, the `UITextField` will be handled something like this.

```
// View controller subclass conforming to UITextFieldDelegate protocol
class MyDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // Set an IB Outlet to the text field in storyboard
    @IBOutlet myTextField: UITextField!

    override viewDidLoad() {
        myTextField.delegate = self

        // ToolBar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        // Optional styling
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = .black
        toolBar.layer.borderWidth = 0

        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Buttons
        let buttonOne = BarButtonItem(title: "One", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourSelectorOne(_:)))
        let buttonTwo = BarButtonItem(title: "One", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourSelectorTwo(_:)))

        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

       toolBar.setItems([buttonOne, spacer, buttonTwo], animated: false)
       toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
}
```

This will create two buttons, one on the left and one on the right of the toolbar. The type of keyboard can be set in Interface Builder.

To get this by tapping on the text field in the cell directly, without navigating to a new view controller, you could set your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass as the text field delegate.

Note that you will need to provide method stubs to conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. These are not essential for this example so I have omitted them. XCode will offer to populate them for you.

Comment: got it. this is the approach i was going to use but i thought i could avoid having to navigate to another viewcontroller just to present the view. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things in your code you want to change.

1) This view's frame causes that strange behavior:

```
UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.bounds.width, height:view.bounds.height))
```

2) The reason why you make this mistake is because you are confusing

```
.inputAccessoryView
.inputView
```

3) The gif you posted is based on navigationBar buttons. Basically, it by tapping on the cell it presents a detailedViewController with two items set in navigationBar